# How to merge two arrays of objects based on a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

I have two objects as you can see:

```
let arrObj1 = [{"ID":5045,"unread":1},{"ID":5058,"unread":2}];
let arrObj2 = [{"ID":3006,"id":"818", "From":"user1@mail.com"},{"ID":5045,"id":"2503", "From":"user2@mail.com"},{"ID":5058,"id":"2509", "From":"user3@mail.com"}];
```

I would like to merge this two array of objects and want to result to be like:

```
result = [{"ID":3006,"id":"818", "From":"user1@mail.com", "unread":0},{"ID":5045,"id":"2503", "From":"user2@mail.com", "unread":1},{"ID":5058,"id":"2509", "From":"user3@mail.com", "unread":2}]
```

If the ID from arrObj2 is not found in arrObj1 add the "unread": 0
Can anyone help me please

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const 
  arrObj1 = [{"ID":5045,"unread":1},{"ID":5058,"unread":2}],
  arrObj2 = [{"ID":3006,"id":"818", "From":"user1@mail.com"},{"ID":5045,"id":"2503", "From":"user2@mail.com"},{"ID":5058,"id":"2509", "From":"user3@mail.com"}];

// get map of ID as key and unread as value from arrObj1
const IdUnreadMap = arrObj1.reduce((map, { ID, unread }) => 
  map.set(ID, unread)
, new Map);
// iterate over arrObj2 and set unread from map or 0
const merged = arrObj2.map(item => {
  const unread = IdUnreadMap.get(item.ID) || 0;
  return { ...item, unread };
});

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: Why this works `new Map`? Shouldn't it be `new Map()`?

Comment: Thank you very much Majed, This worked like magic mate